# How to limit the bandwidth of an opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, low-pass

A circuit i made using opamps and transistors causes lots of oscillations (parasitic maybe ?), a solution to that which i find very reasonable is to limit the bandwidth of my main driving opamp so any oscillations are attenuated/removed. .[image]

Update : adding a 100uF cap between pin 14 and ground removed about 99% of the oscillations , but instead i got this voltage spike that occurs when i drive the motor with a square wave ( the spike appears with every falling edge)

Comment: and your question is ... ?

Comment: I'd try putting a small (1/10 the series resistance of the motor) between your transistors and the motor. I suspect your wildly reactive load is causing your problem.

Comment: @Neil_UK the oscillations are causing a direct short between the power supply rails through the darlingtons, thats why i want to filter these oscillations out !

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast would removing C42 make it any better ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem with the TIP147 as per your other related question?

Comment: How did you rule out the first op-amp? Are you guessing? I would add a few dozen pF across the feedback resistor of the *first* op-amp. I would also add 100nF directly on the power pins of the opamp, about 0R3 in the emitter circuits of both transistors, and a Zobel network across the load.

Comment: @EJP there are 100nf for every supply rail for the opamps  , so far i kept adding 220nf caps at the feedback resistor and it reduced the noise a little bit, C42 also helps alot ! will add the zobel network and see what happens

Comment: Shouldn't that RC snubber across the motor have an R?

Comment: @AndrewMorton how much should i put in there? it wasn't intended to be an RC snubber .

Comment: 100uF is far too high coming out of an almost zero output impedance. Where did you get that idea? Try 1uF like C42. And are you sure the oscillation isn't happening in the first op-amp?

Comment: @EJP i was trying random stuff and it worked , and yea iam sure now the oscillations are mainly happneing at the final opamp and the motor, i know 100uF is too high but i thought its fine since the input signal is mostly DC .

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the question, your problem is with your phase and gain margins of the Op-Amp. 
To solve this problem, you might have two options, first you can add a compensation capacitor at the output of the Op-Amp (between Node14 and ground). The cap would reduce Unity-Gain Bandwidth of your Op-Amp and hence corrects your phase margin. 
Second, you can reduce gain of feedback loop (the feedback here is the wire from emitter of Q1 to node 13). In order to reduce feedback loop you can simply use a resistive divider.
These topics are addressed here:
http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/course/2/2.010/www_f00/psets/hw3_dir/tutor3_dir/tut3_g.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change or "limit" the frequency response of the opamp unit - however, you can limit the bandwidth of the loop gain (which is responsible for oscillatory behaviour). This can be done, for example, with a R-C series combination BETWEEN both opamp inputs (nodes 12 and 13). This is a kind of "input frequency compensation". Without knowing the exact loop gain response, one could start with R=100...500 ohms and C=100nF.

Comment: will test it out and comeback to you ..! , how can i calculate the exact values for the RC combination ?

Comment: There are no "exact values". The effect od the RC combination is as follows: For low frequencies there is no effect (as long as the capacitive impedance is very large). With rising frequencies, the loop gain will be reduced twofold (decreasing feedback factor as well as decreasing openlöoop gain of the opamp). It is important that the feedback factor reaches its final value for frequencies above w1=1/RC before the loop gain is unity at a frequency wt. Rule of thumb: w1 should be app. one decade lower than wt (because of the phase condition).

Comment: See here: Fig. 29 and Fig. 30 in http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/an94/an9415.pdf and Fig. 18 in http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/38-06/capacitive_loading.html?doc=CN0343.pdf

Comment: thanks for your feedback , i'll make sure to let you know when it works !

Comment: adding a cap across R24 helped alot, but i still get oscillations when the input voltage is in the range between (0 volts to -0.5volts)

Comment: Did you try the method as described in both references I gave to you?

Comment: i did but it didn't work , the RC series network malfunctioned the whole system.

Comment: Perhaps the capacitive loading of the 2nd opamp are responsible for oscillations. Can you use 3rd opamp wired as a unity gain buffer between opamp and transistor base nodes?

Comment: its not possible the PCB has already been made :/

Comment: What is the DC voltage at the opamp output? This voltage defines the type of operation of the transistors (B or A-B or A). Perhaps a positive voltage (transition to A operation) can help? This should be easy because the 1st opamp produces this DC voltage.

Comment: the goal is to drive the motor with a Varying DC voltage from -10 to +10 volts , so thats the output of the opamp.

Comment: Ah I see - the problem is certainly that the PCB already exists. So - what can be done?